# VS2012 doesn't compile this code, but G++, clang, and ICC all accept it without a diagnostic

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596632/3657206), I came up with [this code](https://godbolt.org/g/6DrQUN) for a constant tree structure in C++:

```
#include <tuple>
struct T
{
    T(const char* n, const T& n1, const T& n2, const T& n3, const T& n4):
        name(n), nodes(n1, n2, n3, n4) {}

    const char* name;
    std::tuple<const T&, const T&, const T&, const T&> nodes;
};

T n(0, n, n, n, n);
```

GCC (both 4.5.3 and recent versions), ICC (17), and CLang (3.5 and recent versions) all compile this code (CLang 3.5 issues a `-Wuninitialized` warning for it, but that's OK as `n` is a placeholder whose value is irrelevant).

Yet, MSVC 11 (VS2012) pukes a C2065 error on the definition of `n`:

> test6.cpp(12) : error C2065: 'n' : undeclared identifier

What gives?  Is MSVC rejecting valid code? Am I off in UB-land with demons flying out of my nose?  If this is not valid, can someone please tell me what in the Standard makes it invalid and/or why GCC, Clang, and ICC all accept it?

Comment: Even if this is valid C++, this is not really a good idea...

Comment: `std::tuple` is available in the c++11 standard. VS2012 doesn't support that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- if nothing depends on the value of our placeholder `n`, why is having it be uninitialized be bad?  Or is there a different problem you're pointing out? (I'd rather do something better, but not having much of C++11 in my toolkit means that I'm pretty constrained...)

Comment: This test case can be shortened to just `int i(i);`. That's the part that VC++ is not accepting. Your `struct T` and your tuple are not relevant for this problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ VS2012 *does* support most of the *library* features in C++11 (see [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) for details)

Comment: @hvd -- they are relevant to making the history of the problem clear though -- would you rather I showed both the code that originally prompted this *and* the fully minimized testcase?

Comment: _@LThode_ I think @hvd got it right, the new syntax isnt supported.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- ...what new syntax?

Comment: It's valid by the standard as hvd shows below, yet it's clearly a very bad thing to do, and should be considered a bug in the standard. Just be happy MSVC caught it for you and wonder why CLang and GCC didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortening this to a simple

```
unsigned char x(x);
```

and testing this online on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ shows that current versions of Microsoft's compiler still reject it.

This is a compiler bug. Quoting the standard (N4140, roughly C++14, but the rule is the same in earlier standards):

> **3.3.2 Point of declaration [basic.scope.pdecl]**
>
> 1 The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 12;
> { unsigned char x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second `x` is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. -- *end example* ]

Both `= x;` and `(x);` are grammatically an *initializer*, and there is no exception anywhere that says that in the `(x);` syntax, the variable `x` would somehow not yet be in scope.

Visual Studio's compiler does accept it with the `= x;` syntax.

But as it only affects code where a variable is used in its own initialisation, a better re-working of the code would simply avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: Hmm, `struct x; int x(x);` Function or variable?

Comment: This is obviously an insane thing to allow: *the second `x `is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value*. So it's a bug in the standard, which the compiler rightly corrects.

Comment: @T.C. Same as the most vexing parse: if it can be a function, it's a function. But I don't understand the wording of [dcl.ambig.res]: "the resolution is to consider any construct that could possibly be a declaration a declaration" I do not see how that covers the examples that immediately follow, or the one you gave, where a function declaration is favoured over a variable declaration.

Comment: @Ben -- since you're so adamant that this is a bug in the standard -- then how would you create a [self-referential data type intended for compile-time initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586323/how-to-encode-large-complex-constant-data-structures-in-c)

Comment: @LThode I am not saying that the definition of the point of declaration is a bug. There is nothing that requires one to initialise a value with the value of an uninitialized variable (as opposed to the address of an uninitialized value which may be initialised later.) Allowing that is a bug, and using it as an example of the point of declaration is insane.

Comment: This seems like of those times where a compiler bug is useful as if flags something the coder almost certainly did not intend. And isn't reading uninitialized data always UB.

Comment: @doug: Only if a trap representation occurs. `unsigned char` is the only data type for which this is not possible. Not that the difference matters much in practice.

Comment: @ChristianHackl C++ doesn't have trap representations, that's a C thing. In C++, an uninitialised object has an indeterminate value, and reading an indeterminate value has undefined behaviour, even for types that cannot have what C would call trap representations. There's a special exception for `unsigned char`, but even then it only applies in a few limited cases (including the one in this answer). See [dcl.init]p12.