# Nested C++ constant data structures without initializer lists or explicitly naming all nodes -- VC++2012 destroys inner elements prematurely?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So, I am trying to use a variation of the approach from [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586323/how-to-encode-large-complex-constant-data-structures-in-c) to implement a large-ish, somewhat wide, constant tree structure in C++ (using VC++2012 with the v110 toolchain), as shown below:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    test(const char* n, const test& n1, const test& n2):
        name(n), nodes(n1, n2)
    {
        if (name)
            std::cerr << "test() " << name << std::endl;
    }

    ~test()
    {
        if (name)
            std::cerr << "~test() " << name << std::endl;
    }

    const char* name;
    std::tuple<const test&, const test&> nodes;
};

const test n = test(0, n, n);

test t = test("blah", test("bleh", n, n), n);

int main()
{
    std::cerr << "get " << std::get<0>(t.nodes).name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, instead of outputting the expected

```
test() bleh
test() blah
get bleh
~test() bleh
~test() blah
```

or something of that ilk, I get

```
test() bleh
test() blah
~test() bleh
get
```

and then the program dies with a segfault (i.e. the Windows "this program has stopped working" box) when it tries to access the prematurely destroyed inner object.  Is this my fault for assuming that making a temporary a const reference held subobject of another object would extend the lifetime in the same way a local or global named const reference would?  Or is this a problem with VC++2012 not realizing that the temporary is being captured by reference in the parent object constructor when it should be doing so (i.e. not destroying the inner object until the outer object gets disposed of?)

Answer (score 0):

This bit: `std::get<0>(t.nodes).name` is never going to work properly in your current code, whatever else is going on. That is because `nodes` contains references: `std::tuple<const test&, const test&>` instead of instances.

As a result when you pass the inner object: `test("bleh", n, n)`, it is not copied into the `nodes` of the outer one. Therefore, when it goes out of scope and it is destroyed, your outer object's `nodes` (`t.nodes`) contains references pointing to the great beyond. As a result your program is going to take exception to that statement and crash with a segfault.

EDIT to add:

To clarify: the object that goes out of scope is the value of: `test("bleh", n, n)`

In this statement: `test t = test("blah", test("bleh", n, n), n);`

Because by the time `t = test("blah",...)` returns the inner object `test("bleh",...)` is gone. Note that `t` is actually a *copy* of the value of `test("blah",...)`, the original temporary is also gone. (Well it gets more complex when you consider that the compiler may choose to optimise and do a move instead of a copy, but the semantics are as though it were a copy.)

Comment: The question is "when the heck should it go out of scope?" as my understanding is that a temporary that gets bound to a name (const reference) has its lifetime extended to the name's scope...does that only work for direct assignment, not parameter passing or other forms of name binding??

Comment: It is the temporary that you pass which goes out of scope.

Comment: @LThode - The temporary is bound to the constructor parameter, and has that life time. The lifetime extension is not transferred further.